# Ecommerce api in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, api

For eCommerce Api in laravel which will be user by the mobile application.
Should i use any type of key authorization. If i doesn't use any key auth then all product information will be open and access by any one.

what to do and how to do application authentication in laravel

Comment: If your going for API only, check Lumen. It is Laravel's slimmed down version specifically made for APIs so it is faster. Also, for authentication I would recommend JWT Auth. Key based authentication.

Comment: But JWT Auth auth via email id and password. I want my SPA application access the API without login securely.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the normal user authentication to get your users logged in to the system. Group your routes with the product-related functionalities with Laravel's authentication middleware to make sure those routes are only accessible for your logged-in users.

For key authorization and other secure methods, you will have to check with the e-Commerce service API's options. With my personal experience, I recommend Stripe e-Commerce service. It is very developer-friendly and comes with lots of flexible and secure features.

If you need some support to implement user authentication and Stripe payments to your system with basic app structure, you can refer the [Laravel Shopping Cart](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSJbGtTlrDami-tDGPUV9-w) video tutorial series provided by [Mindspace Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSJbGtTlrDami-tDGPUV9-w).